# How can I immediately pipe tasks from one ThreadPool to another?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I've got a list of input elements which I want to queue into several ThreadPools. Let's say this is my input:

```java
final List<Integer> ints = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

These are the three functions I want the elements to run through each after another:

```
final Function<Integer, Integer> step1 =
        value -> { // input from the ints list
            return value * 2;
        };

final Function<Integer, Double> step2 =
        value -> { // input from the previous step1
            return (double) (value * 2); //
        };

final Function<Double, String> step3 =
        value -> { // input from the previous step2
            return "Result: " + value * 2;
        };
```

And these would be the pools for each step:

```
final ExecutorService step1Pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
final ExecutorService step2Pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
final ExecutorService step3Pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

I want each element to run through `step1Pool` and apply the `step1`. As soon as one element is done its result should
end up in `step2pool` so that `step2` can be applied here. As soon as something in `step2Pool` is done it should be
queued in `step3Pool` and  `step3` should be applied.
On my main thread I want to wait until I have all the results from `step3`. The order in which each element is processed
doesn't matter. Only that they all run through `step1` -> `step2` -> `step3` on the correct thread pool.

Basically I want to parallelize the `Stream.map`, push each result immediately to the next queue and wait until I've
got `ints.size()` results from my last thread pool back.

Is there a simple way to do achieve in Java?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that CompletableFuture will help you here!

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = ints.stream()
            .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> step1.apply(i), step1Pool)
                    .thenApplyAsync(step2, step2Pool)
                    .thenApplyAsync(step3, step3Pool))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> result = futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use streams for that :

```
List<String> stringList = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(100)
                .parallel()
                .map(step1)
                .map(step2)
                .map(step3)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```